# Intellij IDEA Designer for an Applet

Tags: java, intellij-idea, designer, japplet

I'm trying to design an applet using the designer delivered with Intellij IDEA. I have no idea where I can find an option to make one. Solutions have been posted on the net, but seem to be outdated at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

Create this class in your application

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
public class Main extends Applet {
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawString("SALAM Applet", 20, 20);
    g.drawString("سلام اپلت", 20, 40);
}
}
```

- Right click on your applet class and select create 'Main'.
- Click OK.
- Run

for more information visit [this link](http://valk.id.au/blog/awesome/how-to-run-java-applets-in-intellij-idea/)

Comment: There is no "Main' entry in context menu.